# Field 'bookRepository' in 'BookServiceImpl' required a bean of type 'BookRepository' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring-boot, jsp

I'm new to the Spring framework and trying to create `Spring-Boot` combined with `JSP` to make a small web app. However, When I run the program, I get the following error.

Full stack trace:

```
2022-01-01 15:31:43.790  INFO 20116 --- [  restartedMain] spring.jsp.JspApplication                : Starting JspApplication using Java 11.0.13 on cudayanh with PID 20116 (C:\Users\PC_1\Desktop\java_spring\spring-boot-jsp\jsp\target\classes started by PC_1 in C:\Users\PC_1\desktop\java_spring\spring-boot-jsp\jsp)
2022-01-01 15:31:43.791  INFO 20116 --- [  restartedMain] spring.jsp.JspApplication                : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2022-01-01 15:31:43.916  INFO 20116 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2022-01-01 15:31:43.917  INFO 20116 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2022-01-01 15:31:47.098  INFO 20116 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-01-01 15:31:47.112  INFO 20116 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-01-01 15:31:47.112  INFO 20116 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.56]
2022-01-01 15:31:47.115  WARN 20116 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : This listener must only be nested within Server elements, but is in [TomcatEmbeddedContext].
2022-01-01 15:31:47.115  INFO 20116 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : Loaded Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.31] using APR version [1.7.0].
2022-01-01 15:31:47.116  INFO 20116 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true], UDS [true].
2022-01-01 15:31:47.116  INFO 20116 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
2022-01-01 15:31:47.123  INFO 20116 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.1.1l  24 Aug 2021]
2022-01-01 15:31:47.499  INFO 20116 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner     : At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
2022-01-01 15:31:47.515  INFO 20116 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-01-01 15:31:47.515  INFO 20116 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3596 ms
2022-01-01 15:31:47.623  WARN 20116 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'bookController' defined in file [C:\Users\PC_1\Desktop\java_spring\spring-boot-jsp\jsp\target\classes\spring\jsp\controllers\BookController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'bookServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'bookRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'spring.jsp.repositories.BookRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value="spring.jsp.repositories.BookRepository")}
2022-01-01 15:31:47.626  INFO 20116 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2022-01-01 15:31:47.653  INFO 20116 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-01-01 15:31:47.713 ERROR 20116 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field bookRepository in spring.jsp.services.impl.BookServiceImpl required a bean of type 'spring.jsp.repositories.BookRepository' that could not be found.

The following candidates were found but could not be injected:
        - User-defined bean
        - User-defined bean method 'provideBookRepository' in 'JspConfiguration'

Action:

Consider revisiting the entries above or defining a bean of type 'spring.jsp.repositories.BookRepository' in your configuration.
```

I've tried to fix this by referring and using a bunch of solutions, other people provided out there like adding `@Service`, `@Repository` to the implementation class. However, none of them worked.

`repositories/BookRepository.java`

```
public interface BookRepository {

    Collection<Book> findAll();

    Optional<Book> findById(String isbn);

    Book add(Book book);
}
```

`repositories/impl/InMemoBookRepositoryImpl.java`

```
@Service
@Primary
public class InMemoBookRepositoryImpl implements BookRepository {

    @Autowired
    private final Map<String, Book> booksStore;

    public InMemoBookRepositoryImpl(Map<String, Book> booksStore) {
        this.booksStore = booksStore;
        this.booksStore.putAll(booksStore);
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<Book> findAll() {
        if (this.booksStore.isEmpty()) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }

        return booksStore.values();
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<Book> findById(String isbn) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(booksStore.get(isbn));
    }

    @Override
    public Book add(Book book) {
        booksStore.put(book.getIsbn(), book);
        return book;
    }
}
```

`services/BookService.java`

```
public interface BookService {

    Collection<BookDTO> getBooks();

    BookDTO addBook(BookDTO book);
}
```

`services/impl/BookServiceImpl.java`

```
@Service
@Primary
public class BookServiceImpl implements BookService {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("spring.jsp.repositories.BookRepository")
    private final BookRepository bookRepository;

    public BookServiceImpl(BookRepository bookRepository) {
        this.bookRepository = bookRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<BookDTO> getBooks() {
        return bookRepository.findAll()
                .stream()
                .map(BookServiceImpl::convertBookDto)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Override
    public BookDTO addBook(BookDTO bookDto) {
        final Optional<Book> existingBook = bookRepository.findById(bookDto.getIsbn());
        if (existingBook.isPresent()) {
            throw new DuplicateBookException(bookDto);
        }

        final Book savedBook = bookRepository.add(convertToBook(bookDto));
        return convertBookDto(savedBook);
    }

    private static BookDTO convertBookDto(Book book) {
        return new BookDTO(book.getIsbn(), book.getName(), book.getAuthor());
    }

    private static Book convertToBook(BookDTO bookDto) {
        return new Book(bookDto.getIsbn(), bookDto.getName(), bookDto.getAuthor());
    }
}
```

`controllers/BookController.java`

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/book")
public class BookController {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("spring.jsp.services.bookService")
    private final BookService bookService;

    public BookController(BookService bookService) {
        this.bookService = bookService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/books")
    public String getBooks(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("books", this.bookService.getBooks());
        return "booksList";
    }

    @GetMapping("/addBook")
    public String addBook(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("book", new Book());
        return "addBook";
    }

    @PostMapping("/addBook")
    public RedirectView addBook(@ModelAttribute("book") BookDTO bookDto, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
        final RedirectView redirectView = new RedirectView("/book/addBook", true);
        BookDTO savedBook = bookService.addBook(bookDto);
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("savedBook", savedBook);
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("addBookSuccess", true);

        return redirectView;
    }
}
```

The main method

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "spring.jsp")
@EntityScan("spring.jsp")
@ComponentScan({ "spring.jsp" })
public class JspApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(JspApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JspApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

And finally, the `pom.xml` configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
     <!-- <packaging>war</packaging> -->
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>jsp</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--  specifies the Tomcat JSP dependency(jsp parser) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>   

        <!--  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

         <!-- JSTL tag lib -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--  running in a Tomcat web container. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <!-- lombok -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.18</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Your `BookRepository` is not annotated to be Autowired. Try annotating it with `@Repository`.

Comment: @ArunSudhakaran you mean in here `repositories/BookRepository.java`?

Comment: @ArunSudhakaran I've tried adding both `@Service` and `@Repository` as the annotation, but the error still remains.

Comment: `@Repository
public interface BookRepository {}`

like this?

Comment: @ArunSudhakaran yep! I've tried adding in both interface and implementation as well.

Comment: Where is your `JspApplication` class located (its package I mean)?

Comment: @JoãoDias it's inside the `/src` directory by default. I didn't touch it at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try simplifying your main class and rely on the annotations defaults as follows:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan("spring.jsp")
public class JspApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(JspApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JspApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

`@SpringBootApplication` encapsulates `@Configuration`, `@EnableAutoConfiguration`, and `@ComponentScan` annotations with their default attributes. The default value for `@ComponentScan` means that all the sub packages on the package the `@ComponentScan` is used are scanned. That is why it is usually a good practice to include the main class in the base package of the project.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `mvn clean package` and restart the spring application from your IDE afterwards.

I had the same issue and this solved it.